# Android WebView Injected Javascript always indicate lineNumber 1

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I injected some Javascript code into `WebView` following [this](http://lexandera.com/2009/01/injecting-javascript-into-a-webview/). Basically, I override the `onPageFinished` callback of `WebView` and inject javascript files through `webView.loadUrl("javascript:"+myJSCode)`. `WebView` version is 4.0.0. 
Besides, I override the `onConsoleMessage` callback to track my javascript in the `WebView`. When a line of js code is executed, I use `console.log('lineCounter')` to display the line number of the code in LogCat.`<br>`
This works fine in my demo project, all the code are executed and the line number are logged correctly. But one thing I'm confused is that the `consoleMessage.sourceId()` of those js code seems to be empty.

> logCat:
>  
>    Console, JS 1, lineNumber 2 of  
>    Console, JS 2, lineNumber 4 of  
>    Console, JS 3, lineNumber 6 of  
>    Console, end of JS, line number 8 of

When I add this function to my dev project, issues arise. I do the same step as what I did in the demo project. The code is executed in order, but the lineNumber is always 1, and it throws `uncaught syntaxError, unexpected identifier` before finishing executing all js code. Besides, this time, `consoleMessage.sourceId()` is displayed as the url of `WebView`.

> logCat:
>  
>    Console, JS 1, lineNumber 1 of https:// xxx/home 
>    Console, JS 2, lineNumber 1 of https:// xxx/home 
>    Uncaught SyntacError, unexpected identifier

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I had a similar issue, if you have single line comments in your js code that might be the origin of your exception. Dunno why it keeps pushing all JS into a single line though.

Comment: I try a test with only two lines of code `console.log('test1');\nconsole.log('test2')`. And the two lines still display the same lineNumber as 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this issue by using [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) to compile all injected js code. No exception is thrown, but the lineNumber still remains to be 1.